# Unexpected `Unknown' result in theory with finite set

Tags: cvc4

I want to show satisfiability of a simple vehicle configuration problem, in which any vehicle must have one wheel.

Here is the encoding:

```
(set-logic ALL)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-sort Vehicle 0) ; type Vehicle


(declare-sort Wheel 0) ; type Wheel
(declare-fun wheels (Vehicle) (Set Wheel)); wheels: Vehicle -> Set(Wheels)

; number of wheels per vehicle
(assert (forall ((v Vehicle)) (= (card (wheels v)) 1)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

I ran it with [CVC4 online](https://cvc4.github.io/app/), and got this:

```
unknown
(
; cardinality of Vehicle is 1
; cardinality of Wheel is 1
(define-fun wheels ((BOUND_VARIABLE_349 Vehicle)) (Set Wheel) (as emptyset (Set Wheel)))
)
```

I would expect it to be satisfiable, with 1 vehicle having a set of 1 wheel.  Does it fail because the types are open ?  I tried with enumerated types without success.

Trying with [CVC5 online](https://cvc5.github.io/app/) results in this:

```
(error "Parse Error: /code.txt:10.50: Symbol 'card' not declared as a variable")
```

Comment: I tried with enumerated datatypes, and it failed too.

Comment: For CVC5, use `set.card` instead of `card`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CVC5; use `set.card` instead of `card`.

In either case, CVC will not be able to answer your query, because mixing quantifiers makes the logic semi-decidable. Note that when quantifiers are present, you can describe infinite sets; which takes the logic to the semi-decidable fragment. So, don't expect CVC to be able to answer your queries about sets when you use quantifiers.

(See https://cvc5.github.io/docs/cvc5-1.0.2/theories/sets-and-relations.html for an example how quantifiers allow you to specify infinite sets.)